# How to upload and inject image to tinymce 4 using Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce-4

So because there is **absolutely** no **modern** way of uploading images to tinymce in **.net for free**, I was thinking of maybe adding a file upload input in html then upload it to server using ajax and then include the file in tinymce editor.

The problem is injecting image to tinymce, I don't know how to...

Is there any way?

Comment: Yes there is a way, my last project did it, I can post code tonight if nobody has answered it by then, don't recall of the top of my head how it was achieved.

Comment: I just did it and it works fine! see my other post (answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, Micro$oft or someone else needs to really do something about this, in the mean time here is the result of hours of debugging:

This solution uses direct upload function (already there in Tinymce but disabled by default) and with some jquery hack we inject the image into textarea.

Changing dimensions must be done after injecting the image. In the recent versions of Tinymce they also added some nice image editing tools that also work with this method.

Now the code:

This is the action that needs to be placed in a controller: (Mind the routing)

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string path;
        string saveloc = "~/Images/";
        string relativeloc = "/Images/";
        string filename = file.FileName;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 && file.IsImage())
        {
            try
            {
                path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath(saveloc), Path.GetFileName(filename));
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "<script>alert('Failed: " + e + "');</script>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "<script>alert('Failed: Unkown Error. This form only accepts valid images.');</script>";
        }

        return "<script>top.$('.mce-btn.mce-open').parent().find('.mce-textbox').val('" + relativeloc + filename + "').closest('.mce-window').find('.mce-primary').click();</script>";
    }
```

And this is the complete code for Tinymce, it will generate a text box and a couple of hidden fields. It will also make an instance of tinymce with some plugins enabled.

```
    <iframe id="form_target" name="form_target" style="display:none"></iframe>

<form id="my_form" action="/admin" target="form_target" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden">
    <input name="file" type="file" onchange="$('#my_form').submit();this.value='';">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | ltr rtl",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ],
    file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
    if(type=='image') $('#my_form input').click();
}
});
</script>

<textarea id="my_editor" class="mceEditor">This will be an editor.</textarea>
```

**You need to make a folder named "Images" in your project root for uploading images. You also need Tinymce js file and jquery.**

**Change the action of the form according to your setup!!!**

You may also choose to use html helpers. I don't like them. but go ahead and use those instead of this handmade form if you like.

The idea is from [here](https://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/direct-image-uploads-in-tinymce-4-42/) but it was done in python so I rewrote it to work with ASP.NET MVC5 and Latest version of TinyMCE.

I will keep working on this in the next few days and will edit this answer if necessary.

Comment: Hello, could you help me a little so to understand the matching of fields and forms in the javascript?I mean lets say what I need to put in the field_name? I manage to display the icon but it is inactive. Thank you

Comment: @touinta, I tested this code on TinyMCE 4.2 and it works fine, not sure about other versions. Which version are you using?

Comment: Where do you use your Upload action? There is no url in your js code pointing to that action.

Comment: @VincentZHANG After `iframe` there's a `form` tag and there's the `action` attribute that should point to your action method. In the above code it's pointing to `/admin`

Comment: @VSG24 Thank you, this is a nice solution, it seems to work with TinyMCE 4.4.3 and MVC 5 perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

I did this in TinyMCE 4.3.10

In tinymce.init, put these options:

```
paste_data_images: true,
images_upload_url: '/YourController/UploadImage',
images_upload_base_path: '/some/basepath'
```

In CSharp code:

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    file.SaveAs("<give it a name>");
    return Json(new { location = "<url to that file>" });
}
```

You should be able to copy and paste image to your textarea (strange, drag and drop doesn't work anymore).

Comment: Yes it works. IIRC, in your file_picker_callback handler, detects if it is a local file. Read, encode it with Base64 then insert it as inline image using insertContent(). The above code will still be called. I will update my answer later tomorrow.

Comment: I am using 4.4.3, and this config does not show the browsing file button in image dialog.

Answer (score 1):

this is my config for the latest version of tinymce..

> File_browser_callback is depreciated

..and it works..this works on copy paste,insert image. I haven't tried with file upload manager yet

```
         automatic_uploads: true, << auto run your upload script

         images_upload_url: 'ImageUpload', <<your upload, I'm using mvc and I'm routing to "ImageUpload"

        images_reuse_filename:true, << this is where the return json from your code i had a hard time finding this out.  

       file_picker_types: 'image', << type where the upload will appear images dialog,link or file

        //custom file picker       
        file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

        // Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without 
        // even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
        // or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
        // just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
        // once you do not need it anymore.

        input.onchange = function () {
            var file = this.files[0];

            // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
            // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
            // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
            var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
            var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
            var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
            blobCache.add(blobInfo);
            console.log(id);
            console.log(blobCache);
            // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
            cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
            console.log(meta.filetype);



        };

        input.click();


    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I work in a JSF/Java web application and this code in *tynymce.init* javascript bellow worked fine for me.
The pictures are saved in the middle of the text field (I suppose). I guess there's no need for aditional code

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",
      browser_spellcheck: true,
      paste_data_images: true,
      plugins: [
        "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "table contextmenu directionality template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
      ],

      toolbar1: "bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
      toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image code | insertdatetime preview | forecolor backcolor",
      toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",

      menubar: false,
      image_advtab: true,
      toolbar_items_size: 'small',

      file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
          if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
                var inputFile = document.createElement("INPUT");
                inputFile.setAttribute("type", "file");
                inputFile.setAttribute("style","display: none");
                inputFile.click();
                inputFile.addEventListener("change", function() {
                var file = this.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                  callback(e.target.result, {
                    alt: ''
                  });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
             });
          }
        },

      insertdatetime_dateformat: "%d/%m/%Y",
      insertdatetime_timeformat: "%H:%M:%S",
      language: 'pt_BR',
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

API_KEY  - replace with yours for tinymce
Selector - replace
MVC Controller in 'Control' Area

```
  <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/API_KEY/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#Body',
            menubar: ' edit view insert format tools table',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist  | forecolor backcolor removeformat | emoticons | fullscreen  | image media  link | code',
            plugins: 'code importcss  searchreplace autolink   visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media   codesample table charmap hr  nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists  wordcount   imagetools textpattern noneditable   charmap   quickbars  emoticons',
            contextmenu: "link image imagetools table",
            image_advtab: true,
            toolbar_sticky: true,
            images_upload_url: '/Control/Home/UploadImage',
            paste_data_images: true,
        });
    </script>
```

**C#**

```
namespace Project.Areas.Control.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public class HomeController : WebBaseController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            var uploadsPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"/uploads");
            var uploadsDir = new DirectoryInfo(uploadsPath);
            if (!uploadsDir.Exists)
                uploadsDir.Create();

            var imageRelativePath = $"/uploads/{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.jpg";
            var imageAbsPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(imageRelativePath);
            var imageBytes = file.InputStream.ReadToEnd();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(imageAbsPath, imageBytes);
            return Json(new { location = imageRelativePath });
        }
.....
```

**Extension Method**

```
public static byte[] ReadToEnd(this Stream input)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                input.CopyTo(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```